# Simply edit custom line from .txt with PHP

Tags: php

Txt file:

`Line 1 
Line 2 
Line 3 
Line 4`

`$contents = file_get_contents('file.txt');
$contents[1] = "Sample edit.";
file_put_contents("file.txt",$contents);`

Eddited txt file:

`Line 1 
Sample edit. 
Line 2 
Line 3 
Line 4`

But it's not working for me.

Comment: You are so close to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next code is one way to do it. Pay attention to the comments in the code :

```
<?php
$line = 2; // LINE TO REPLACE.
$my_array = file( "my_file.txt" ); // GET WHOLE FILE AS ARRAY OF STRINGS.
$my_array[ $line ] = "abc" . "\n"; // REPLACE THIRD LINE (2). NOTICE THE "\N".
file_put_contents( "my_file.txt",             // SAVE ARRAY IN FILE.
                   implode( "",$my_array ) ); // CONVERT ARRAY INTO A BIG STRING.
?>
```

This is the idea : read the entire file as an array (`file`), now you can replace the desired line by its index, then you convert the array as string (`implode`), and save it to file (`file_put_contents`).

Comment: Thx so much ^^ It works well. :-)

Comment: @FandaSoudek, you may click the checkmark to accept the answer :)